# Excel: Distribute one percentage through multiple cells

Tags: excel

I have cells with the following percentages:

A1 = 81% 
A2 = 15% 
A3 = 3% 
A4 = 1%

I'm trying to make it so whatever is in A1 gets redistributed across the values in A2, A3, and A4 with the same ratio between them. For example, A4 to A3 is a 3x increase and A3 to A2 is a 5x increase. So distributing the 81% will make the new values in A2, A3, and A4 equal 100% but maintain the original ratio.

So, for the above example, taking 81% and distributing across A2, A3, and A4 you'd get the following values:

B2 = 64% 
B3 = 13% 
B4 = 4% 
B2 + B3+ B4 = 81 (value in A1)

The Ratio won't always be perfect due to rounding, which is fine.

If you add the A2 + B2, A3 + B3, A4 + B4, and sum it all you get 100%. The goal is to get this to work regardless of the original 4 starting numbers in A1:A4.

Thanks!

Comment: whats your input and what output are you expecting?

Comment: @nullpointer The inputs should be able to be changed. There will only be 4 cells A1, A2, A3, and A4. They have to add up to 100%, but I only want cell A1 to be distributed across A2, A3, and A4. The three new values can be in separate cells (call it B2, B3, and B4) which will add up to 100%, but maintain the same ratio between A2 to A3 and A3 to A4.

Comment: do you mean A1 would be unique and the remaining percentage would be distribute amongst others such that A2 will always be 5x of A3 and A3 will always be 3x of A4?

Comment: @nullpointer all values will be unique. The ratio between A2 and A3 can change as well. The goal is to have all four of the numbers be able to be changed and have whatever number is in A1 cell distrubute across A2, A3, and A4 maintaining their original ratio. Hopefully I'm describing it well enough.

Comment: question not clear to me sorry

Comment: @nullpointer added additional information to the original question with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snapshot shows a solution ...

[image]

where cells E2 adn E3 sum columns B through D.

```
=SUM(B2:D2)
```

and cells B3 through D3 contain the following formula ...

```
=(B2/$E$2)*$A$2+B2
```

Oops sorry - just saw the edit to the question.

Replace the formula in Cells B3 through D3 with

```
=(B2/$E$2)*$A$2
```

[image]

Comment: Worked flawlessly -- thank you!